# In PicasaWeb, how can I find pictures that contain Person A and Person B?

Tags: picasa-web-albums

I've used PicasaWeb's facial recognition tools to tag all the people in my pictures... now is there a way to search for pictures that contain specific groups of people?

Examples:

- Alice AND Bob
- Carl ONLY
- David NOT Edgar
- Frank OR George

(I know you can do the AND case using the checkboxes on the people tab)

Comment: Picasa or PicasaWeb? Their feature sets are not identical, and the former will be off-topic for this site.

Comment: I didn't think about the ambiguity; I'm going for the on-topic picasaweb answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to search in your own photos (unless I'm missing something), so you can't really do much, but I'm pretty sure in the future they will add better search options.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this isn't possible - I assume this offical FAQ is where any information pertinent to this would be posted:

http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97960

Would be great functionality to have one day.